# Using types that are exported indirectly via `typeof`

Tags: typescript

I'm importing a file that has the following types declaration:

```
declare class FIFO {}
declare const _default: typeof FIFO & {
    default: typeof FIFO;
};
export = _default;
```

And I want to use it like this:

```
import FIFO from '/path/to/fifo';
export default class Foo {
  queue = new FIFO ()
};
```

I don't think this code has any problem whatsoever, i.e. I would be able to generate proper types for this file, but TypeScript v3.1.6 is complaining with:

```
Public property 'queue' of exported class has or is using name 'FIFO' from external module "/path/to/fifo" but cannot be named.
```

What am I supposed to do? I can't export the `fifo` module in a different manner, and I want proper types declarations generated for my file.

Comment: in the usage you also need to export `FIFO` so consumers of `Foo` can infer the member field properly.

Comment: I said "I can't export the fifo module in a different manner"